# Move to the end one character with rangy

Tags: javascript, range, selection, contenteditable, rangy

I have a contenteditable div, I want to move the range just one character after the current one.

I currently want to check if the character after caret is a certain character, and if it is then place caret after it

I use this code but it don't work

```
 placeCaretAfterHiddenCharacter:function(containerEl,afterCharacters) {
    var afterChar = "", sel, range, afterRange,rangeHtml;
    sel = rangy.getSelection();
    if (sel.rangeCount > 0) {
        range = sel.getRangeAt(0).cloneRange();
        var endRange = rangy.createRange();
        endRange.selectNodeContents(containerEl);
        endRange.collapse(false);

        range.setEnd(containerEl, endRange.endOffset);

        var div = this.cloneSelectionInDiv(range);
        //to get string as html as range removes the html and returns the text only
        rangeHtml = div.innerHTML;
        afterChar = rangeHtml.slice(afterCharacters-1);

        if(/[\u200B\u200C\u200D\uFEFF\u2028\u2029]/g.test(afterChar)) {
            range.setStartAfter(range.startContainer,range.startOffset);
            range.collapse(true);
            sel.addRange(range);
        }

    }
},
```

the `afterChar` gets set right but the caret does not move.

how can this be done ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Rangy 1.3's [TextRange module](https://github.com/timdown/rangy/wiki/Text-Range-Module). For example, to move the caret one character forwards, you could do the following:

```
rangy.getSelection().move("character", 1);
```

Comment: I see that its in beta, is it stable for use ?

Comment: I would say it's quite stable. There are no serious known bugs and the code has been around for a couple of years. The majority of the outstanding work before a full release is updating demo pages and documentation.

Comment: Thanks!!! I've been in this issue for days, really much appreciated work at Rangy